# How can i change media URL to amazon s3 bucket in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on website in which i have copied the media library files into Amazon s3 bucket. Now i want that my website should read the media files from that Amazon s3 bucket.

I have made search and replace in database but attachments(media) are still using old URL.

For example : Current URL of a file is

```
http://x.x.x.x/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/icon38.png
```

But I want Wordpress to read this attachment from 
http://s3.amazonaws.com/website-assets/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/icon38.png

These are dummy URL.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Amazon CloudFront Distribution and define the content URL in WordPress' Configuration wp-config.php file using the following:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://static.example.com/contentdirectory');
```

Comment: cloudfront gives me a url like: https://db7has3256zq.cloudfront.net - is it possible to use "mydomain.de" instead of this cryptic url somehow?